# Checking if every character in a c# string is the same character

Tags: c#

Starting with any string, I need to ascertain whether that string comprises one or more instances of only a specified single character. For example "£££££" would pass my test, "wertf" would fail. The approach I have taken is as follows:

```
string source = "any string";
char[] candidate = source.ToCharArray();
char validCharacter = '£';

    if (candidate.Length > 0)
    {
        // (code removed) if candidate length = 1 then just test candidate[0] against validCharacter
        bool isValid = true;
        int index = 0;

        while (index < candidate.Length - 1)
        {
            if (candidate [index] != validCharacter )
            {
                isValid = false;
                break;
            }

            index++;
        }

        if (isValid)
        {
            // success, do what needs doing
        }
    }
```

This works, as you would expect, but I can't help but feel that I might be missing a trick here. Is there a better, more concise, way of doing this that doesn't sacrifice the clarity of the above?

Comment: will string.IndexOfAny() be helpful?

Comment: From your description "AAAAA" would pass. But your code only passes for strings containing only "£". Which is it you want?

Comment: I want to test for a specific character, I've used '£' as the example here but it could be any specific character.

Comment: I edited your question to make that clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable.All<TSource> Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx)

```
bool result = (str.Length > 0 && str.All(r=> r == str[0]));
```

This would be efficient than using `Distinct` and `Count()`

For your case it can be:

```
string source = "any string";
char validCharacter = '£';
bool result = source.Length > 0 && source.All(r=> r == validCharacter);
```

Comment: All these years of using Enumerable methods and I never knew there was an All()! Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You just check with simpler code whether a string has the same character:

```
if (source.Distinct().Count() == 1)
{
    // Pass
}
```

**Edit:**

If you need to check string comprises one or more instances of only a specified single character, you can use `All`:

```
if (input.All(c => c == specificChar))
{
    // Pass
}
```

Comment: Though, if you have a 2GB string that starts with `aab...`, it will take a while ;)

Comment: yes, it is very short but there will be no performance compared to the authors original code.

Comment: @Knaģis: yes, but performance would be trivial if you don't have very long string, you can get very simple code with high readability

Comment: Which probably won't be a problem as the last time I have encountered a 2GB string starting with `aab` was... never.

Comment: This would need the overload of Distinct that takes an IEqualityComparer<char> so that a test for a specific character could be performed, I think.

Comment: on my i7 100Mb random string takes about 3sec. The performance seems to be linear on the string length.

Comment: The point is that an efficient algorithm would bail at the first non-matching character. This one churns through the whole string even if the first character is a mismatch. The All() solution is fine though.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Distinct()` to remove duplicates and compare the character counts.

```
var pass = mystring.Count() > mystring.Distinct().Count();
```

**EDIT**

I misread and thought it was a duplicate of any character in the test string.  The following is correct for "one or more instances of only a single character".

```
mystring.Distinct().Count() == 1
```

Comment: Fails for strings with length of 1

Comment: "a".Count() > "a".Distinct().Count() = false, which is correct as there are no duplicates.  How does this fail?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do this:

```
if(source[0] != validCharacter) return false;

bool isValid = true;
for(int i = 1 ; i < source.Length; i++)
{
  if(validCharacter != source[i])
  {
    isValid = false;
    break;
  }
}
```

Things to note: immediate fail if the first character doesn't match. `string` already implements `IEnumerable<char>`, so no need to use `ToCharArray` with the extra allocations. The loop starts at index 1, always comparing to the first item and breaking as soon as it fails.

This is likely to be more efficient for long strings than `Distinct`.

Comment: it would probably perform slightly faster if you would check against `validCharacter` and not `source[0]`.

Comment: @Knaģis - True. No need for that lookup.

Answer (score 1):

```
string test1 = "Test";
string test2 = "TTTT";

test1.All(a => a == test1[0]);
test2.All(a => a == test2[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your algorithm you don't need the `.ToCharArray()`. Just retrieve the character using `source[index]`. This way you will only be reading the memory and reading every character just once.

Your code is the optimal solution. There are many tricks using LINQ but most will perform much worse. Any tricks with code like `source.Trim(source[0])` will result into unnecessary creation of new strings and thus also in worse performance.

See the answer from Oded♦ that shortens your existing code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is probably going to be the fastest, you could compact it somewhat by using a `for` instead of a `while`

```
for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++) {
    // existing equality check
}
```

Alternatively, here's another inefficient but more compact method (as it creates a new string in memory and checks against):

```
if (source == new String('£', source.Length)) {
    // valid
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
 string str = "test";
            char b = '£';
            bool isValid = false;
            foreach (char a in str) 
            {
                if (!a.Equals(b)) 
                {
                    isValid = false;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Regex.IsMatch(candidate, "^£+$")) {
   // whatever it is you want to do
}
```

... or of course ...

```
if(Regex.IsMatch(candidate, "^" + Regex.Escape(validChar) + "+$") { ... }
```

`Regex.Escape()` is there in case `validChar` is a character with meaning in regular expressions, like `*`, `.` etc.

These are short, declarative (as long as the reader understands regular expressions), efficient, performance scales to long strings, and the idiom extends to more complicated patterns.